# How to count odd/even number in each row and put that value in another column

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to get the number of even/odds numbers in each row and put the value in another column such as coleven and colodd. This code only lets me do it one row at a time instead of doing it to all rows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('allornothingev.csv')
print(df) 
row_list = df.loc[0, :].values.flatten().tolist()

#view results
print(row_list)
count_odd = 0
count_even = 0
for x in numbers:
        if not x % 2:
             count_even+=1
        else:
             count_odd+=1
print("Number of even numbers :",count_even)
print("Number of odd numbers :",count_odd)
```

Comment: If you want to show code, use the built-in method. Try not to leave screenshots, and give a minimal, reproducible copy of your code.

Comment: please attach sample code

Comment: You have to go through the dataframe rows and count the number of even and odd numbers and append the counts to lists. The lists are used to add the new columns. This is some code that I wrote to do this: https://pastebin.com/UXSDyQkH

Answer (score 1):

Modulus is helpful in finding if a number is odd or even. [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo)

for an even number you can do `x % 2 == 0`, for odd `x % 2 == 1`

You can do this operation combined with some logic and depending on the result put it in a odd or even column.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

# create a toy dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a" : np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000),
    "b" : np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000),
    "c": np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)
    })

# create columns
df.assign(
    coleven = lambda x: x.apply(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, axis=1).sum(axis=1),
    colodd = lambda x: x.shape[1] - x["coleven"]) # to save doing the same thing over again, I just do number of columns minus coleven. This is assuming all columns are numeric
```

Comment: Pretty neat how you find the odd numbers

Comment: No need for apply, `df['coladd'] = df.mod(2).sum(axis=1)` is enough. Also you have an off-by-one error since `x.shape` increased by 1 after the first assignment ;)